# Why do I get a parser error in my program?

Tags: haskell

I've written a Haskell program for [problem 25 on Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=25). I think my program should run and return the correct answer, but it doesn't:

```
-- Problem25.hs
module Main where

fib :: Int -> Integer
fib 1 = 1
fib 2 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

length1 :: Integer -> Int
length1 = length . show

main :: IO ()
main = do
  list1 <- [1..]
  list2 <- zip3 list1 list1 list1
  list3 <- map funct list2
    where funct u v w = (u, fib u, length1 (fib u))
  putStrLn "number : "                                                 -- line 17
  putStrLn $ show . head . ( dropWhile ( \(u,v,w)-> w < 1000  ) list3)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
$ ghc Problem25.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Problem25.hs, Problem25.o )

Problem25.hs:17:3: parse error on input `putStrLn'
```

Why do I get the parser error? I'm in a `do` block, so `putStrLn "number : "` should be fine, right?

Comment: Always post the __exact__ error message.

Comment: @zeta the first only led to quite a few more ... this would be never-ending but hunt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok here is a version with all syntax errors removed:

```
module Main where

fib :: Int -> Integer
fib 1 = 1
fib 2 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

length1 :: Integer -> Int
length1 = length . show

main :: IO()
main = do
  putStrLn "hello"

  let liste = [1..]
  let liste2 = zip3 liste liste liste
  let liste3 = map funct liste2
  putStrLn "number : "
  putStrLn $ show . head $ (dropWhile ( \(_,_,w)-> w < 1000  ) liste3)  
    where funct (u,_,_) = (u,fib u,length1 (fib u))
```

as you can see there are quite a few:

- `where` in the middle of a `do` block -> this has to go to the end
- `<-` instead of `let ... = ...` - remember: `<-` is to *pull out* values form computations - in this case to get an `a` from an `IO a`
- one `.` to many in the last `putStrLn` (the last part with `dropWhile` is a value not a function)
- a few places where you have to use a 3-tuple argument instead of the curried version as you choose to go with `zip3` (that returns tuples)

also note that while this compiles and runs it will most likely not be a good (or even feasible) solution - I did nothing more than remove your syntax problems - to get a good solution you should first work on your `fib` (which does not perform very well - there are better ways to compute it - hint: search for Haskell + Fib on your fav. search engine)

here are a few remarks:

- you don't need the `zip3` part with 3 times the same list - you can let your `funct` do this work (which btw: you already do - you ignore the second and third argument)
- why do you `dropWhile` and then take the head? (`filter` and head seems more natural IMO)
- of course you should also rethink the `funct` part (notice how you never need the middle item from the tuples?)

Good luck with the rest of the exercise ;)

---

### a bit cleaned up

I cleaned up your solution a bit:

```
fib :: Int -> Integer
fib 1 = 1
fib 2 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)

length1 :: Integer -> Int
length1 = length . show

solve :: Int
solve = head . filter ((>= 1000) . length1 . fib) $ [1..]

main :: IO()
main = do
  putStrLn "number : "
  print solve
```

that's still not better performance wise (that's your challange) but at least it works for `3` digits instead of `1000` (although even `10` will take quite some time with this ...)

**enjoy**

---

### cannot help it

I had to try it and indeed if you define the sequence like this:

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)

fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = unfoldr fib (1,1)
  where fib (n,m) = Just (n,(m,n+m))
```

(which is near to what you would usually do in a loop)

you get the answer rather quickly (`4782`)

of course you have to think about how to get the *index* to this (hint: now a `zip` might be a good idea)

Comment: `unfoldr`? Why not `fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`? (That's the variant I use and see more often)

Comment: because I like them `unfolds` ;) (but this should get similar results sure) - why don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: even 10000 is reasonable fast and takes only about 300MB or so for the list :D

Comment: Huh? 300MB? Is `unfoldr` not subject to list fusion? `ghc -e "let fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs) in Data.List.findIndex (>10^10000) fibs" +RTS -s` yields 21MB total memory usage.

Comment: using GHCi in Emacs :D (why botter compiling it)

Comment: [`-e`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/modes.html) doesn't compile :D. By the way, `unfoldr` also uses 20MB, so I guess there's something else. \*shrug\*

Comment: well almost makes me go back to PE again :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94980/discussion-between-zeta-and-carsten).

Comment: hello, thanks for your replies, I tested the unfoldr function and it works fine, it's very quick.